# parsing xml using boost

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I am trying to parse an `XML` with the first tag as `roottag` , but when I execute the below code it is always going to catch segment. Not sure what am I doing wrong with `BOOST_FOREACH`.

The output I get is shown below:

```
entered in loop
In catch
```

update:

I printed the `boost property tree` read by `read_xml` it is showing me as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

and the error I got is no such node
```

The code :

```
boost::property_tree::ptree pt1;
boost::property_tree::read_xml( "/home/user/test.xml", pt1  );
try{
    std::cout<<"\n entered in loop";
    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type & node, pt1.get_child("roottag"))
        {
            std::cout<<"\n entered in loop 2";
            //copy data
        }
}
catch(...){
    std::cout<<"\n In catch";
}
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<roottag>
    <shipTo country="US">
        <name>Alice Smith</name>
        <street>123 Maple Street</street>
        <city>Mill Valley</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>90952</zip>
    </shipTo>
    <billTo country="US">
        <name>Robert Smith</name>
        <street>8 Oak Avenue</street>
        <city>Old Town</city>
        <state>PA</state>
        <zip>95819</zip>
    </billTo>
    <comment>Hurry, my lawn is going wild!</comment>
    <items>
        <item partNum="872-AA">
            <productName>Lawnmower</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>
            <comment>Confirm this is electric</comment>
        </item>
        <item partNum="926-AA">
            <productName>Baby Monitor</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
            <shipDate>1999-05-21</shipDate>
        </item>
    </items>
</roottag>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to catch an exception and see what is the problem?

`catch(boost::property_tree::ptree_error & e){
    std::cout<< "Error is:" << e.what();
}`

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine.

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b00bb25ed84087a)</kbd>**

Printing:

```
 entered in loop
 entered in loop 2
 entered in loop 2
 entered in loop 2
 entered in loop 2
```

Comment: could it be an xml encoding issue?

Comment: Yes. And: yes. To both questions